# Boolean functions- depth of generated function and info

Tags: combinatorics, boolean-algebra

I'm looking for a general book/link to information about boolean function (Function from to {0,1}), we've introduced them in a logic course but it seems we won't focus on them.

Comment: To get curly brackets in Mathjax, escape them with a backslash: `$\{0,1\}$` gives $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some references which could be useful

> - *[And/Or trees revisited](http://chauvin.perso.math.cnrs.fr/andor.pdf)* by P. Flajolet etal. This is one of *some* references about the subject you are interested in from the following book:
> - *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick. Search this book for the string *boolean* and you will find some interesting examples.
> - *[Random Boolean Expressions](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by D. Gardy is a survey about this topic and also mentioned in the book above.